# Spring boot state machine Perform some actions before evaluating guards

Tags: java, spring-boot, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I am trying to find a way to perform actions before the guards are evaluated like want to add API response into the extended state object which is triggered for a specific State and event and based on that response want to evaluate the guards. But I am unable to find any listener or interceptor that serves the purpose.

I am new to spring boot state machine. Can somebody please help?

```
@Override 
  public void configure( StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<RedactionStates, 
         RedactionEvents> transitions) throws Exception 
         { 
           transitions 
             .withExternal() 
             .source(RedactionStates.R1).target(RedactionStates.R2) 
             .event(RedactionEvents.E1) 
             .action(c -> { // Make the API Call // Store in the extended state }) .guard(new G1(COMPLETED)) 
             .and() 
             .withExternal() .source(RedactionStates.R1) .target(RedactionStates.R3) 
             .event(RedactionEvents.E1) 
             .guard(new G2(SKIPPED)) 
             .and() 
             .withExternal() .source(RedactionStates.R1) .target(RedactionStates.R4) 
             .guard(new G3(IN_PROGRESS)); 
        }
```